# Spring boot embedded tomcat what is the folder structure created in deployed machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

If we run sprin-boot:run in linux

where will be the tomcat running path.
what will the folder structure of tomcat for jar and war. 
will there be any work or webApps folder created?

How to find the tomcat path in linux,will it be running as separate tomcat service or the java application service.

suppose any hot fix deployment with jsp change, which was possible if there is a webapps, is it possible with spring boot?

Comment: I assume that you create an executable JAR and will startet it with java -jar <yourjar.>jar, right? Then the Tomcat is embedded in the jar. And there is no WAR. Or do you ask anything else?

Comment: suppose its a spring boot web application or WAR to deploy,so, will it be any other tomcat service running or its the java application service.

Answer (score 1):

You deploy Spring Boot as an executable JAR and run it using `java -jar`.  It's the main class that is executed.

Tomcat or Jetty is the HTTP listener; it's running inside Spring Boot.  It's the reverse of creating a WAR and deploying it to Tomcat.

There's no work or web apps folder created.

Comment: so, will it be any other tomcat service running or its the java application service.

Answer (score 0):

**Embedded Servers in Spring boot**

The idea of Embedded Server is to make the server part of the application,so in this case to be able to deploy directly to the virtual machine,you only need to have virtual machine with java already installed.

for using embedded service using tomcat you will need to have this conf in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

starter-tomcat itself also has these dependecies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
  <version>8.5.23</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
  <version>8.5.23</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
  <version>8.5.23</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which are the tomcat dependency enough to run your application as a single jar on it's own.

---

**Summary**

> in spring boot when we create an application deployable, we would embed the server inside the deployable (for example tomcat). this means, you can generate an application jar which contains Embedded Tomcat. You can run a web application as a normal Java application.as a result, When you execute `mvn spring:boot run` it's exactly equivalent as executing `java -jar` command but maven also make sure about some suble considrations:
>
> - your application are given the right parameters
> - making sure your application already compiled

---

**More Info**

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html